# Drupal 6 - Get node->links in blocks

Tags: php, drupal, hyperlink

I want to display $node->links in a block, but node_load only loads the node object without the links. How do I get the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, node links are pulled by hook_link() so you could do:

```
$links = theme('links', module_invoke_all('link', 'node', $node, $teaser));
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this module help? 
http://drupal.org/project/link_node

Comment: If I understand it correctly, that module provides an easy way to make links to nodes. What I'm trying to achieve is accessing the links array in the $node object from a block. That module wont help me, but thanks for answering and trying to help!